# Creating a Matrix - "Value update is not a member of Example.Matrix" error

Tags: arrays, scala, compiler-errors, mutable

I am trying to create a simple matrix (basically porting some code I wrote in C++ to understand Scala better). The code I wrote is:

```
object Example extends App {
  case class Matrix(rows: Int = 1, columns: Int = 1) {
    val data = Array.fill[Int](rows * columns)(0)
    def apply(i: Int, j: Int) = this.data(i * columns + j)
  }

  val grid = Matrix()

  grid(0, 0) = 10
}
```

This does not compile, but from what I can tell this is equivalent to my working C++ example logically. Clearly something weird is going on due to the apply function.

Can someone please explain why this code is not compiling? I cant seem to figure it out.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val foo = gir(0, 0)` will call `apply`, but `grid(0, 0) = foo` will call `update`.

You need to define it like this:

```
def update(i: Int, j: Int, x: Int): Unit = {
  this.data(i * columns + j) = x
}
```

BTW, a **case class** must not be mutable! So, please use a normal **class**.
And, it may be good to make `data` private.

---

Anyways, mutability in general as well as **Arrays** are not common in **Scala**.
IMHO, the best way to understand **Scala** better is not try to port imperative code, but rather rethink functional solutions to the same problems.